# Fragment callbacks even though it is not part of UI

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am writing an app that uses Fragments for the UI, very similar to the Notepad sample code.  It has a List of items then an editor for these items.  In landscape mode the list and editor fragments are positioned side by side, but in portrait mode only the list is shown in the main activity, and the editor is shown by launching a new activity.

Within my editor fragment I have calls to findViewById to get at the individual components of the UI (mostly EditText fields).  Under normal conditions this all works fine, but when the screen is rotated from landscape to portrait and the main activity is destroyed and created again it seems to call onActivityCreated (plus other callbacks) on my editor fragment even though it is not part of the display now (since in portrait mode it is just the list that is shown).

The problem is, findViewById to get the UI components returns null (I'm guessing because the fragment is not being displayed).  But why are the calls being made at all?  It is making me need null checks everywhere to make sure I don't try and use the UI components when they aren't on screen.

Comment: did you provide a two layout XML files? One for your landscape mode as well as one for portrait. onActivityCreated shouldn't be called unless you are accidentally adding the fragment at runtime or your layout file still contains that fragment for that screen orientation

Comment: Yes, I have a folder layout-land and layout.  The layout files don't reference the editor fragment directly.  The landscape layout has a FrameLayout component as a placeholder for the editor fragment.  I only ever use a FragmentTransaction to insert the editor fragment if I am in landscape mode.  And the problem only occurs when I go from landscape to portrait.

Comment: By placing breakpoints and debugging I can see that onDestroy is being called on my fragment and the only place in my code where I commit a FragmentTransaction is not being called again. So onCreateActivity is being called on the same Fragment that has already been destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when the screen is rotated from landscape to portrait and the main activity is destroyed and created again it seems to call onActivityCreated (plus other callbacks) on my editor fragment even though it is not part of the display now (since in portrait mode it is just the list that is shown).

Correct. Android recreates all existing fragments during a configuration change. Or, if the fragment was added using a `FragmentTransaction` and you used `setRetainInstance(true)`, the exact same fragment object is retained during a configuration change.

> But why are the calls being made at all?

See above.

> The problem is, findViewById to get the UI components returns null

You only need to call `findViewById()` in `onCreateView()`, and there you know whether the "UI components" exist, because you are creating them yourself.

> It is making me need null checks everywhere to make sure I don't try and use the UI components when they aren't on screen.

Then use `isVisible()` or one of the other `is...()` methods on `Fragment`. Or, use `setRetainInstance(true)` so your fragment is  not destroyed and recreated. Or, remove the `Fragment` (e.g., in `onCreate()` of the activity, if the passed-in `Bundle` is not `null` and you are now in portrait).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I still don't see why the fragment is recreated on orientation change given that in portrait mode the fragment is not part of the activity, but I got the solution to my problem.  I was using findViewById in onActivityCreated by calling getActivity().findViewById.  Since the fields aren't part of the activity I was getting null.  I used your advice and moved that code to onCreateView and first inflated my view then called findViewById on the view. So that never returns null.

Comment: @DaveJohnston: "I still don't see why the fragment is recreated on orientation change given that in portrait mode the fragment is not part of the activity" -- once created, fragments are forever, until explicitly removed, or until the activity is finally destroyed (i.e., not destroyed as part of a configuration change).

Comment: so should I be detecting the orientation change and explicitly removing the fragment or is it normal to leave it as it is?

Comment: @DaveJohnston: Heh, for stuff like this, I don't know what "normal" is.